# Load xib file for iPhone6 automatically

Tags: ios, xib

my iPhone App designed for iPhone5 has a xib file
I would like to modify the xib file for iPhone6 and at run time load the xib file based on whether I am running on iPhone5 or iPhone6

I realize that there is a ~convention for naming xib files
foo~iphone.xib
foo~ipad.xib

Is there a ~ convention that will automatically load a xib file for iPhone6 or do I have to write code to load the xib manually?

Comment: Better to adopt autolayout in your existing nib file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load same nib file for both iPhone5 and iPhone6 that you don't have to do any thing, it will automatically load the nib for both device.
But you have to check that have you added the "Launch images" or "LaunchScreen.storyboard" for iPhone6 size, if not add those other wist the iPhone5 size will scaled to fit iPhone6 size.

Comment: I want my app to load a different xib for iPhone6